# What do we call the random profile pictures we get in online sites?

Tags: word-request

Is there a term for the "profile picture" which is given randomly to the users who join an online forum or social networking sites such as *Hangouts* and the very own *Stack Exchange*, where we get a random picture.
Take an example of my profile picture of this site given below. What do we call it?

[image: Stack Exchange identicon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the possible terms which come to my mind:

## Identicon:

> An Identicon is a visual representation of a hash value, usually of an IP address, that serves to identify a user of a computer system as a form of avatar while protecting the users' privacy.

## Avatar:

> In computing, an avatar (also known as a profile picture or userpic) is a graphical representation of a user or the user's alter ego or character. It may take either a two-dimensional form as an icon in Internet forums and other online communities.

---

This is an **identicon**:

[image]

This is an **avatar**:

[image]

---

Source:

• Identicon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon

• Avatar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(computing)

Comment: Note that an identicon is also an avatar. (Just a confusing one.) But an avatar is not an identicon.